# Translating languages in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

Is there no way to use Google Translate to translate InDesign files? I would like to translate my text boxes from English to a few other languages, and save each language as a different file.

Comment: I've always done this via copy paste.

Comment: As a regular user of translated software, I beg you not to do that. A lack of translation is better than a wrong translation, which often happens with Google Translate, and will happen very often with short texts, which give little context to the software.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you have to copy the type and paste it into Google Translate.